# c++ overloaded friend function can't access private members

Tags: c++, c++11

Currently doing a project where my professor requires us to overload the stream extraction and input operators. I have copied the header that he gave us to start my implementation. Here's my header student.h:

```
// @file student.h
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Student {
    /** add all the setter and getter methods **/
    /**
   * @param is the input stream
   * @param course the student object reference
   * @return the input stream
   */
    friend istream &operator >> (istream &is, Student &student);
    /**
   * @param os the output stream
   * @param course the student object reference
   * @return the output stream
   */
    friend ostream& Student::operator << (ostream& os, const Student& student);

public:
    Student();
    Student(string firstName, string lastName, int id, char grade);

    void setFirstName(string firstName);
    string getFirstName();


private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int id;
    char grade;
};
#endif /* STUDENT_H */
```

And here is the definition I'm using the the file student.cpp

```
#include "student.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


istream &operator >> (istream &is, Student &student) {
    is >> student.firstName;
}
```

CLion keeps telling me that firstName is private and therefore inaccessible, is there anything obvious I'm missing? I've checked and double checked my formatting and moved the ampersands around a lot and I'm having a lot of trouble telling what it is.

And yes, I've already looked at the similarly titled question where he was having issues with the namespaces he was using, tried it and saw no results. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a typo. `operator<<` should not have the `Student::` part. Having fixed that, your code compiled for me on MSVC 14.1, clang 5.0.0 and GCC 7.3.

Comment: The Student:: is leftover from some things I was trying, but I'm still getting the same issue, it should be irrelevant as it's not defined yet anyway.

Comment: For what it's worth, GCC refused to compile without fixing it because it treated it as a member `operator<<` which needs to take exactly one argument. But the important part of my comment was that I am not getting your error on three different popular compilers. Clion doesn't have a compiler if I'm not mistaken, so what *are* you using?

Comment: Well. CLion lied to me. It ran perfectly fine when I made a small test function to see if it was *actually* inaccessible and it is completely accessible. I'll report the bug and swiftly scream out a window because that cost me hours. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, CLion did not lie to you. The bug is in your actions.

Comment: Did the header you were given really have `using namespace std;`?  If so, you need to explain to your professor [why that's bad practice](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721).

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain the error message, but the function has to return a value.

```
istream &operator >> (istream &is, Student &student) {
    return (is >> student.firstName);
}
```

Fix that and the missing constructors, etc., and `main()`, and it should compile just fine.

P.s. Put class Student in a namespace that's yours, all yours, and never ever ever write`using namespace std;` in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is `using namespace std;` in header file in global scope. This can lead to troubles so do not do it.

Personally I do not like this pattern that stream operator is friend of the class. So I do it like this:

```
class Student {
public:
    Student();
    Student(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, int id, char grade);
    void setFirstName(std::string firstName);
    string getFirstName();

    std::istream &scan(std::istream &input);
    std::ostream &print(std::ostream &output) const;

private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int id;
    char grade;
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, Student &student) {
   return student.scan(input);
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const Student&student) {
   return student.print(output);
}
```

For compiler there is no difference.
This pattern also open doors for other solutions, like static polymorphism, regular polymorphism (in this cases you do not have to define stream operators for each class).